# Converting Ruby DateTime format to regexp

Tags: ruby, regex, validation, datetime

I'd like to convert a datetime format string like `"%m/%d/%y %H:%M"` into a regular expression. I won't know what is in the format string, and I don't have to handle every case, so I've been trying to just gsub into the string.

```
DATEFORMAT = "%m/%d/%y %H:%M"

def date_format_to_regex
  format = DATEFORMAT
  format = format.gsub(/\//,'\/')
  format = format.gsub(/%[ymdCHI]/,'[[:digit:]]{2}') #two digits
  format = format.gsub(/%[YMS]/,'[[:digit:]]{4}')    #four digits
  @date_regex = Regexp.new(format)
end
```

But the output of that screws up a lot of the slashes

```
"%m/%d/%y %H:%M == (?-mix:[[:digit:]]{2}\\/[[:digit:]]{2}\\/[[:digit:]]{2} [[:digit:]]{2}:[[:digit:]]{4})"
```

Comment: I'm no Ruby expert, but I don't think you want to escape your replacement `/` in the first gsub call.  Escape on the left, not on the right.

Comment: `'\/'` is the same as `"\\/"` - the `/` does not need escaping if not inside `/regex string literal/` => try deleting `format = format.gsub(/\//,'\/')`...

Comment: Yeah, the first gsub doesn't seem to actually do anything... what were you trying to get ultimately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DATEFORMAT = "%m/%d/%y %H:%M"

def date_format_to_regex    
  format = DATEFORMAT.gsub(/%[ymdCHI]/, "\\d{2}").gsub(/%[YMS]/, "\\d{4}")
  @date_regex = Regexp.new(format)
end
```